# run first aid from recovery mode

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-utility

I have Macbook Air 2017 running Mojave 10.14.4, so I check every month to find out there is a virus or malware on my Mac, usually I only use CleanMyMacX and Malwarebytes so one day before I check my Macbook my friend says try doing first aid and when I check using the help first aid[image] disk utility appears like this

disk utility asks me to do first aid through recovery mode, I do it or not

Answer (score 1):

Better to run sooner than later.  Disk Utility is written by Apple.  Why are you worried. You should have a full backup of your system.

See this article. Pick diskutilty. Run disk first aid.
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314

I read were many people do not recommend running CleanMyMacX.  Could be why you are experiencing problems with your machine. I recommend you stop running CleanMyMacX.  Read manufacture's site on how to uninstall. See:
https://macpaw.com/support/cleanmymac-3/knowledgebase/how-to-uninstall-cleanmymac-3

Simple put,  Apple attempts to provide all the malware detection and removal you need in Mac OS X.

"Effective defenses against malware and other threats" by John Galt
https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-8841

"Avoid phishing emails, fake 'virus' alerts, phony support calls, and other scams"
https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204759

"MalwareBytes Anti-Malware for Mac Removes adware and malware Revives your Mac."  MalwareBytes has a more restrictive filter for adware than Apple. MalwareBytes has come to be accepted as the only malware detector you should consider.  For those pestered by browser attacks consider MalwareBytes.
https://www.malwarebytes.org/antimalware/mac/

etrecheck
Run etrecheck.   The first five runs are free. Provided a report on your machines hardware and software.  Great for diagnosing your system.  Click on the download link at the bottom of the screen.
http://etrecheck.com/

Apple on Security:
https://www.apple.com/business/resources/docs/macOS_Security_Overview.pdf

phishing
"fake" panic warnings
https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-8771
https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204759